# How to display UI proportional to viewport in CSS with content of images?

Tags: html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMU5s.jpg

E1, E2, E3, E4 are UI elements and they will have eventually a hover effect on them. I also have a background image.

Here is what I was able to achieve so far.

```
<div class="bg">

        <img src="bg.jpg" id="bg_id">

        <div class="ui">
            <img id="ui-elem1" src="ui-elem1.png">
        </div>

</div>
```

and in the CSS part I have:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 ;
}

.bg {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

#bg_id {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.ui {
    position: relative;
    width: 50vw;
    left: 10vw;
    top: 75vw;
}
/* 20% of ui */
/* 20% width 4 images = 4*20 = 80% padding = 6.6% */
#ui-elem1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 6.6%;

}
```

My code displays the background image fine, it resizes and it's always proportional to the viewport. But alas, when it comes to the UI I can't see the first UI element there. What to do?

Thank you.

EDIT: Here's a jsfiddle for it. https://jsfiddle.net/vq24a76p/1/ Doesn't show it proportionally to the viewport.

Comment: can u provide JSFIDDLE?

Comment: @Shaik Yeah just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

For this you could use background-image property an set the size to cover just like the example...
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/nz5ex8sc/)

```
.bg {
    background-image:url('https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2014/07/Mount-Fuji-Japan-Wintertime.jpg.1000x0_q80_crop-smart.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size:cover;

}
```

Another approach if you want to use an image tag, is to set the width:100% and height auto, the caveat in this is that some vertical images will have a blank space at the bottom...